# I want to delete the stored image while update new image

Tags: laravel, lumen

I want to delete the stored image while update new image

```
public function update($id)
    {
        $users = AdminLogin::find($id);

        if(Input::hasFile('image_file'))
        {
            $file = Input::file('image_file');
            $name = time() . '-' . $file->getClientOriginalName();
            $file = $file->move(('uploads/images'), $name);
            $users->image_file= $name;
        }
        $users->save();
        return response()->json($users);
    }
```

Comment: Seems you have `$users` is empty

Comment: I  already stored images

Comment: have you dumped `$users` ? and do you have correct `$id` ?

Comment: Any error? What's wrong in your code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can write this. This will solve your problem

```
public function update($id)
{
    $users = AdminLogin::find($id);

    if(Input::hasFile('image_file'))
    {
        $usersImage = public_path("uploads/images/{$users->image_file}"); // get previous image from folder
        if (File::exists($usersImage)) { // unlink or remove previous image from folder
            unlink($usersImage);
        }
        $file = Input::file('image_file');
        $name = time() . '-' . $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $file = $file->move(('uploads/images'), $name);
        $users->image_file= $name;
    }
    $users->save();
    return response()->json($users);
}
```

This will delete the previous image and update the new image

Answer (score 0):

Well, the answer is technically incorrect. What if the save operation fails, since you have deleted that image the current record will not have an image anymore.
So to overcome this problem you can adjust your code like:

```
    if(Input::hasFile('image_file'))
        {

            $file = Input::file('image_file');
            $name = time() . '-' . $file->getClientOriginalName();
            $file = $file->move(('uploads/images'), $name);
            $users->image_file= $name;
        }
        $users->save();
        if(Input::hasFile('image_file'))
           {
               $usersImage = public_path("uploads/images/{$users->image_file}"); // get previous image from folder
               if (File::exists($usersImage)) { // unlink or remove previous image from folder
                  unlink($usersImage);
               }
           }
```